# Django CharField default не работает

Tags: python, django, django-orm

```
username = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='private') # Ошибка (1048, "Column 'username' cannot be null")
username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='private') # Ошибка (1048, "Column 'username' cannot be null")
username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default='private') # Записывает пустоту вместо default
```

Как мне записать мое default значение? При создании модели передаю none в username

Comment: Ну раз вы передаёте None, значит и будет записано именно None. Не передавайте ничего, тогда и будет использоваться default

Answer (score 0):

Очень похоже на то, что ты не провел миграции

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```